# How to configure YARN to restart a Spark driver after time elapsed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark streaming app written in Java.

I would like to restart the driver if it hasn't completed a streaming batch within a predefined time interval.

When throwing an exception from within the driver code without implementing the timer, yarn restarts the application as expected.
When trying to add the timer (which needs to be in a different thread than the driver) and throwing an exception after the allotted time has passed yarn does not restart the driver.
My guess is that the exception needs to be thrown from within the driver thread.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

--supervise is used to  make sure that the driver is automatically restarted if it fails with non-zero exit code.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Quoting the docs you pointed out (highlighting mine): _"For example, with a **Spark standalone** cluster with cluster deploy mode, you can also specify --supervise to make sure that the driver is automatically restarted if it fails with non-zero exit code. "_

Comment: Restarting the driver when it fails works very well.
But I am looking for a way to restart the driver (under the same applicationId) proactively in case it has not finished it's current batch after a certain amount of time.